# ASP.NET Membership.DeleteUser from another Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I have two applications, one is the main site and the other one is the administrative site.
The thing I want to do is remove users that belong to the main site, from the administrative, using `Membership.DeleteUser`.

The problem is that it returns false, although `Membership.GetUser` is returning me the correct user.

Microsoft documentation about DeleteUsers says

> "Users deleted from the database are only deleted from the configured
>   applicationName."

So there's nothing strange to my problem.
I tried deleting a user that was created through my administrative application and it worked. But that's not what I want. Any ideas?

```
 var muser = Membership.GetUser( userId, false );

 if( !Membership.DeleteUser( muser.UserName, true ) )
 {
    throw new Exception( "An error occurred. User not deleted." );
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the default schema and implementation of `Membership`. The providers (`Membership`, `Role`, etc.) all include an `ApplicationName` property that is used, purposefully, to let you use one database for multiple applications but still have your users separated by app. As the documentation explains at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.applicationname%28v=vs.100%29.aspx, you need to programmatically change the `ApplicationName` if you want to delete a user outside of the the current app.